# The website exists but request.head/get times out

Tags: python, python-requests

I have written a Python script to check whether a website exists or not. Everything works fine, except when checking http://www.dhl.com - the request times out. I have tried both GET and HEAD methods. I used https://httpstatus.io/ and https://app.urlcheckr.com/ to check DHL website and the result is error. The DHL website DOES exist! Here is my code:

```
import requests
a ='http://www.dhl.com'
def check(url):
    try:
        header = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 8172.45.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.64 Safari/537.36'}
        request = requests.head(url, headers = header , timeout = 60)
        code = request.status_code
        if code < 400:
            return "Exist",str(code)
        else:
            return "Not exist", str(code)
    except Exception as e:
        return "Not Exist",str(type(e).__name__)

print(check(a))
```

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testing with curl shows you need a couple of other headers for that DHL site

```
import requests

url = 'http://www.dhl.com'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,fil;q=0.8',
    }
request = requests.head(url, headers=headers, timeout=60, allow_redirects=True)
print(request.status_code, request.reason)
print(request.history)
```

Without these headers, curl never gets a response.

Comment: Thanks @JustinEzequiel. It is working now. How can we identify the missing headers? Can you share it?

Comment: I just opened up DevTools on Chrome after browsing to the site.